# Math.floor(Math.random*myArray.length) is returning NaN

Tags: javascript

I'm receiving a bit of a strange error.

I'm trying to select the index of an array at random, so to do this I am using the code below:

`myArray[Math.floor(Math.random*myArray.length)]`

myArray.length is 282, but `Math.floor(Math.random*myArray.length)` is NaN and `myArray[Math.floor(Math.random*myArray.length)` is undefined.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Math.random` is a function it should be `Math.random()`

Try

```
myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)]
```

Answer (score -1):

[Math.random()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp) and [Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random), go through API links.

Your code will be:

```
myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)]
```